# passing int literal to method that takes integer in java

Tags: java, casting, parameter-passing, literals

this is may be the dumbest question ever asked in stack overflow but this is bothering me lot...

```
 public class shorte
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        short e = 56; // no need for explicit cast
        System.out.println(e);
        start(56);  // why does int literal here needs explicit cast ...
    }
    static void start(short e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

while creating normal short variable from an int literal in function didn't ask for any explicit cast , but
why does passing int literal to short variable (parameter passing) needs an explicit cast......??

and again

i now it is not recommended to ask two unrelated questions in single post but this too trivial to ask in yet another post..

**scope of 'for' counter variable **

```
    public class forloop
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int a =12;
        for(int a =12;a<14;++a) // no showdowing of variable ,give compile-time error
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

so i tried it with normal blocks

```
   a=12
{
a=13; even this doesn't compile 
}
```

does that mean, blocks don't have their own scope...

Comment: they have theyr own scope, but that doesn´t mean they ignore everything that was defined previously. Simply `a` was defined before the loop and you redefine a variable with the same name which will cause your compile time error.

Comment: Nobody can answer two answers at once. Please separate your questions, or they will be closed.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html look for integer literals.

Comment: (1) For initialisation with a wider constant java is less strict for ease. As a parameter it was considered to be too unclear, as with method overloading there might two methods with the same name, _Quite arbitrary reasoning._ (2) It was felt that redeclaring the same name in a method was unreadable, error prone and unimaginative bad style, and probably an oversight (reusing an old name), so they made it an error.

Comment: shouldn't compiler at least try to match among declared methods to find best possible one....which in this case is start(short e)...@JoopEggen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `short` literal can be automatically constructed from an `int` literal in Java. This is the case of

```
short e=50;
```

But calling a function and passing parameters is different. Because of the possibility of overloading, the function call should exactly match the function prototype. Imagine an overloaded function with an `int` parameter for one version and a `short` parameter for another.

As for the second question, in most languages, you usually cannot hide an identifier declared in an outer scope by the same identifier in an inner scope. I have two exceptions in my head:

1- A global variable can be hidden by a local variable (in C++ for example, as Java does not have global variables).

2- A class data member can be hidden by a local variable.

In both cases, the language offers a resolution operator (:: for 1- and `this` for 2- ).

Comment: yes!!!,that makes sense,to make shadowing relevant one has to provide a resolution operator to choose between shadowed and shadowing variable......elegant explanation why shadowing can't come into play here @Wabbi

Comment: @viru Glad it was clear. Does anyone have other examples of possible similar shadowing?

Comment: but as far as first question is concerned, shouldn't compiler at least  try to match among declared methods to find best possible one....which in this case is start(short e)....@Wabbi

Comment: The compiler doesn't do that, because there might be another overloaded version of `start` that takes an `int` parameter. This is not the case in your example, but the compiler just does not do it to avoid possible logic errors. @viru

Comment: class parent 
{
int x=90;
}
class child extends parent{//super.x get shadowed
int x =78;
public static void main(String []args)
{
child c=new child();
System.out.println(c.x);
c.start();
}
void start()
{
 System.out.println(super.x);
}}    @Wabbi

Answer (score 3):

Just from the technical point of view (not speculating about the reasons ;-)): It's in [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf)

a)

> 5.2 Assignment Conversion
>
> [...]
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (
> §15.28
> ) of type 
> byte
> , 
> short
> ,
> char
> , or 
> int
> :
> •
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is 
> byte
> ,
> short
> , or 
> char
> , and the value of the constant expression is representable in the
> type of the variable.

b)

> 6.4
> Shadowing and Obscuring
> [...]
> It is a compile-time error if the name of a local variable 
> v
>  is redeclared as a local
> variable of the directly enclosing method, constructor, or initializer block within
> the scope of 
> v
> ; or as an exception parameter of a 
> catch
>  clause in a 
> try
>  statement
> of the directly enclosing method, constructor or initializer block within the scope
> of 
> v
> ; or as a resource in a 
> try
> -with-resources statement of the directly enclosing
> method, constructor or initializer block within the scope of 
> v
> .

Answer (score 2):

Question 2:

```
int a =12;
        for(int a =12;a<14;++a) // no showdowing of variable ,give compile-time error
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

I believe the rationale is that most of the time, that isn't intentional, it is a programming or logic flaw.

in an example as trivial as yours, its obvious, but in a large block of code, accidentally redeclaring a variable may not be obvious.

Question 1:

In the int version, the compiler knows that all the data in the number  can be stored in a short. No information is lost. That's not always true for literal values.